# Opcode Constancy rules

Tags: assembly, x86, opcode

So whenever I run a command on assembly and view it on CPU mode, I have the segment:offset and right  afterwards I have the opcode that resembles the command.
For instance, I run the command `mov ax, 1A1Bh` and it shows me this:

```
cs:0005 B81B1A mov ax, 1A1Bh
```

So my question is, why does `1A1Bh` show up as `1B1A` in the opcode?

And whenever I run `mov ax, dx` it shows me this:

```
cs:0095 8BC2 mov ax, dx
```

From what I understood the opcode for 'mov' is `B`, and for `ax` it is `8`, so why does it show up as `8BC2`?

Answer (score 2):

x86 is little-endian, which means that the low byte of a multi-byte integer is stored at the lower address.  Hence why the bytes of your immediate value show up in opposite order.

x86 instruction encoding is not straightforward - you can't always just pick out various nibbles and say "this must be the mov". If you really want to understand the instruction encoding you need to look at the x86 instruction set reference.

http://www.intel.com/content/dam/www/public/us/en/documents/manuals/64-ia-32-architectures-software-developer-instruction-set-reference-manual-325383.pdf

Comment: I presumed "this must be the mov" because I ran it a ton of times and it did not change. I checked the link, it didn't really help me. I need to find the constancy of assembly in opcodes...

Comment: I have no idea what you're getting at. That document is *the* reference for any questions about x86 assembly. Certain *bits* define the opcode while others specify the operands. Is there something *specific* you're trying to accomplish?

Answer (score 0):

There are many different types of `mov`. Opcode bytes that can mean `mov` (not all of them always mean `mov`) are `88` through `8C`, `8E`, `A0` through `A3`, `B0` through `BF`, `C6` and `C7` (the last two only mean `mov` if the `r/m` field in their ModRM byte is 0).

There is also (depending on what you want to group with `mov`s) `mov`s to/from control and debug registers (`0F 20` through `0F 23`).

`B81B1A` is in a group of instructions that spans `B8` through `BF`, based on the destination register (which is encoded in the opcode). That you saw an 8 was because the destination is `ax`, it has nothing to do with the 8 in `8B` (where both the 8 and the B are truly part of the opcode and not some sneaky operand).

`mov` is complicated. You'll find much more consistency with for example the simple ALU instructions (`add`, `or`, `adc`, `sbb`, `and`, `sub`, `xor`, `cmp` are 0 through 7 respectively), that you can all encode with the same function that takes their index as parameter but further doesn't care which one it is (there are still several cases within that function of course). Other potentially useful groups are the "instructions without operands", "instructions with 1 operand and a fixed `r` field" and "instructions that only have an `r, r/m`-form"

Comment: Can you explain to me in what way does assmebly choose to form an op code for mov ax, dx for example?

Comment: @DorianShullman you'll have to parse the operands as well before you can say what the opcode should be.

Comment: How can I determine the operands? I didn't actually use them, I simply wrote variations of mov register, register

Comment: @DorianShullman you just have to know what they are. If you write `ax, dx` then obviously you already know what they are.

Comment: Actually I don't, I mean they might be embedded, I just don't know about thier existance, I used a sheet which I edited in notepad++ and than I ran it on DOSBOX, didn't use any operands.

Comment: @DorianShullman ok what are you are actually doing? This isn't making a lot of sense right now.

Answer (score 0):

Since the instruction set for the 8086 processor is more basic

[Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/O4TZZ.png)
 is a list of mov opcodes in binary (for an 8086):
[Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5jWDD.png) is a table explaining MOD and R/M

SR stands for segment register, they are ES, CS, SS, DS.

The reference from [datasheet](http://www.electronicsandbooks.com/eab1/manual/Electronic%20Component%20Databook%20Datasheet/Brand/Intel/Databook/1979%20Intel%20The%208086%20Family%20Users%20Manual%20197910%20[760].pdf)

Obviously the machine code for different architectures is going to be different but I find it easier to learn something by starting with where it came from.

(For brevity, the instruction set encoding information begins on page 263)